# Combine 2 scripts

Tags: javascript

I have these 2 scripts but I cant put them work together

```
function start()
{
    var f=document.getElementById("hipaya");
    var s=document.getElementById("paypala");
    var l=document.getElementById("skrilla");

    f.style.display = 'block';
    s.style.display = 'none';
    l.style.display = 'none';
}


function disp_div() {
    var word = document.myform.mycred_buy.selectedIndex;
    var selected_text = document.myform.mycred_buy.options[word].text;

    var f=document.getElementById("hipaya");
    var s=document.getElementById("paypala");
    var l=document.getElementById("skrilla");

    if (selected_text == 'HiPay'){
        f.style.display = 'block';
        s.style.display = 'none';
        l.style.display = 'none';
    }else if (selected_text == 'PayPal ou Cartão Crédito/Débito'){
        f.style.display = 'none';
        s.style.display = 'block';
        l.style.display = 'none';
    }else if (selected_text == "Skrill (Moneybookers)"){
        f.style.display = 'none';
        s.style.display = 'none';
        l.style.display = 'block';
    }
}     
window.onload = function() {
    var calculSumToString = function calculSumToString() {
        totalField.value = (qtyField.value * 0.1).toFixed(2) + " €";
    };

    var totalField = document.getElementById('total_price');
    var qtyField = document.getElementById('amount');

    qtyField.onkeyup = calculSumToString;
    itemPriceField.onkeyup = calculSumToString;
};
```

Does any one have any idea why cant I put then together?
Only one works. If I put the 1st one last, its works but the second stops workin

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "put them together"? In the same file, or in adjacent `<script>` tags in your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Because `itemPriceField` will be undefined (I presume that this is an old name for this variable).

I presume that the line:

```
itemPriceField.onkeyup = calculSumToString;
```

Should be:

```
totalField.onkeyup = calculSumToString;
```

Additionally, your function definition for `calculSumToString` is incorrect, it should be:

```
var calculSumToString = function() {
    totalField.value = (qtyField.value * 0.1).toFixed(2) + " €";
};
```

As to why the javascript does not work at all when the order is the other way around is because the function evaluation will stop on the first error (when trying to access a property of `undefined` or the incorrect function syntax).

jsLinters can pick up this issue for you and can be included as part of a bundling and minification step - I'd recommend having a quick google around these areas if you're interested in creating robust javasscript (in addition to unit test frameworks for your JS).

Comment: script 1 and 2 works fine individual but when they are together one stops workin

Comment: @user3652832 answer updated to cover another error (the calculSumToString function variable is declared incorrectly)